# Check if any form fields have changed upon saving asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, redirect

I've got a large .net form with hundreds of input fields, sometimes users navigate off the form page without saving, what's the best way to check if a field value has changed when they try to navigate away? some c# function or javascript?

Comment: The answer is: javascript. No problem :)

Comment: You can set a dirty flag using jQuery like this: `$(":input").change(function() { dirtyFlag = true;});`

Comment: thanks, i'll go down that route.

Answer (score 2):

Don't take the control out of the users hand :-)

Ask him on exit, if he wants to save the changes. Maybe he did some changes by mistake, which you don't want to save.

You can achieve this by Javascript/Jquery. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    formmodified=0;
    $('form *').change(function(){
        formmodified=1;
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        if (formmodified == 1) {
            return "New information not saved. Do you wish to leave the page?";
        }
    }
    $("input[name='commit']").click(function() {
        formmodified = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: While I absolutely agree, the answer is a bit thin. It might be warranted since the question is equally thin, but lets try to correct that instead of playing by OP's rules :) (obligatory: I did not downvote, but...)

Comment: @Mackan Thanks for your request :-) I improved the answer.